# I cant Stop my video which is playing in YTPlayerView ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

In my ios app I am using Googles `YTPlayerView` to load You tube videos, I can able to Play videos , But i cant able to stop The videos which is playing, on tap of Done button of the webviews Player It is exiting from full screen and automatically opening fullscreen, How do i stop the Videos ? i tried the following code to get notification on tap on Done but its not getting called

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playbackDidEnd:)
                                                 name:@"MPAVControllerItemPlaybackDidEndNotification"
                                               object:nil];
```

Is there any way to stop the videos or is there any way to get notification for Done Button Tap?

I also tried  YTPlayerView's delegate method but it is not called on tap of done
 `-(void)playerView:(YTPlayerView *)playerView didChangeToState:`(YTPlayerState)state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html`, remove or comment below code.

```
window.setInterval(forcePlay, 5000);
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29306099/2696038

Answer (score 1):

Pause your video by adding these lines in `viewDidDisappear` method in your class file `.m`

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.Player pauseVideo];
}
```