# YTPlayerView youtube-ios-player-helper pause not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube

I'm having trouble with the Youtube youtube-ios-player-helper library. I can load a video into the player and it plays but if I tap pause the video stops for a few seconds and then starts playing again.

The incredibly simple UIViewController code to start the video is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.player = [[YTPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT)];

    self.player.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.player];
    [self.player loadWithVideoId:@"bQCjOm4p5jM"];

}
```

I instrumented the didChangeToState delegate method with NSLog as follows:

```
- (void)playerView:(YTPlayerView *)playerView didChangeToState:(YTPlayerState)state {
    switch (state) {
        case kYTPlayerStatePlaying:
            NSLog(@"Started playback");
            break;
        case kYTPlayerStatePaused:
            NSLog(@"Paused playback");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"didChangeToState %d", state);
            break;
    }
}
```

In the Xcode log, when I tap 'play' to start the video playing, I see:

```
didChangeToState 4
```

The value 4 does not appear to be defined in `YTPlayerView.m`. When the video actually starts playing I see the expected `Started playback` log message.

When I tap 'pause', I don't see anything in the log (no `didChangeToState` event triggered - the event I'd expect would be `kYTPlayerStatePaused` per the YTPlayerView docs). However a few seconds later, the video starts playing again, and then I see two consecutive `Started playback` log messages (`kYTPlayerStatePlaying` events). Every time I press 'pause' to try to pause the video, it pauses for a few seconds (with no `kYTPlayerStatePaused` event), but then it starts playing again and I see  `Started playback` log messages.

Anyone else seeing this? Anyone know where to go from here? This is Xcode 6.2 and build target is iOS 8.0.

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution here in the Github issue tracker for the code. Sorry, I guess I missed that in my earlier researching.

The fix described is here: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/86

In `YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html`, remove or comment below code.

```
window.setInterval(forcePlay, 5000);
```

There's another suggested fix that completely replaces the `YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html` file but the above seems to have worked for me. It concerns me that Google's own code for this basic function is so fundamentally broken.

Comment: I realize this is an older post, but I am having this issue with 'youtube-ios-player-helper', '~> 0.1.4' (injected via cocoapods) and the HTML does not contain the above JavaScript code. Has anyone solved this in 0.1.4 of the helper library?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString static *const kYTPlayerStateUnstartedCode = @"-1";
NSString static *const kYTPlayerStateEndedCode = @"0";
NSString static *const kYTPlayerStatePlayingCode = @"1";
NSString static *const kYTPlayerStatePausedCode = @"2";
NSString static *const kYTPlayerStateBufferingCode = @"3";
NSString static *const kYTPlayerStateCuedCode = @"5";
NSString static *const kYTPlayerStateUnknownCode = @"unknown";
```

is mapped to

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, YTPlayerState) {
    kYTPlayerStateUnstarted,
    kYTPlayerStateEnded,
    kYTPlayerStatePlaying,
    kYTPlayerStatePaused,
    kYTPlayerStateBuffering,
    kYTPlayerStateCued,
    kYTPlayerStateUnknown
};
```

loosing the default values and value types.
starting with kYTPlayerStateUnstarted==0
didChangeToState 4 means it's buffering.
Google logic.